# Add an array as request parameter with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm looking for way to add an int array (e.g [0,1,3,5]) as parameter in a **GET** request with retrofit 2. Then, the generated url should be like this : http://server/service?array=[0,1,3,5]

How to do this ?

Comment: did it work on postman?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally founded a solution by using Arrays.toString(int []) method and by removing spaces in this result because Arrays.toString return "[0, 1, 3, 5]". And my request method looks like this

```
@GET("http://server/service")
Observable<Void> getSomething(@Query("array") String array);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you're int[] has space between elements. Also your server should should support that param in string.

Answer (score 21):

You need to name your query param with an array syntax like so:

```
@GET("http://server/service")
Observable<Void> getSomething(@Query("array[]") List<Integer> array);
```

The syntax itself will vary by the backend technology being used, however not including the brackets "[]" will normally be interpreted as a single value.

For example, using `array=1&array=2` will generally be interpreted by backends as only `array=1` or `array=2` instead of `array=[1,2]`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `https:/server/service?array[]=value1&array[]=value2` is what I get

Comment: That's exactly what you should get @Przemo

Comment: @mrstif I thought the questions is about getting `array=[1,2]`, not `array[]=value1&array[]=value2`.

Comment: @XiWei as my answer states that is in fact how most servers normally interpret those values

Answer (score 20):

Just add it as a query param

```
@GET("http://server/service")
Observable<Void> getSomething(@Query("array") List<Integer> array);
```

You can also use int[], or Integer... as a last param;

Comment: I have tried this solution but the generated url looks like this : http://server/service?array=0&array=1&array=3&array=5 but i my case I'm looking for a way to get a generated url which looks like this  http://server/service?array=[0,1,3,5]

Comment: now that is a not very standard way to go. you can try server.service?array=[{array}] and in request use @Path("array") String and feed it with generated string from you array. But I'm not sure if this can go through the Retrofit. Alternatively you can try push it as a query param. @Query("array) and generate the String that you need manually in your case "[1,2,3]"

Comment: @AndrejJurkin The way using @path cannot go through the Retrofit: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "array={array}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.`

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem and had to do a couple of things to reach the acceptable form (as asked in the question).

1. Converted an ArrayList to String

   ```
   arrayList.toString().replace(" ", "")
   ```
2. In RetroFit method, I changed the Query param which accepts the ArrayList above to as follows:

   ```
   @Query(value = "cities", encoded = true)
   ```

This ensures that the brackets and commas are not URL encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Using `toString` didn't work for me. 
Instead, `TextUtils.join(",", ids)` does the trick.

Don't forget to mark the `Query` with `encoded = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Well this did the trick for me

*Step 1 :*

In **StateServce.kt**

```
@GET("states/v1")
fun getStatesByCoordinates(@Query("coordinates", encoded = true) coordinates: String) : Call<ApiResponse<List<State>>>
```

*Step 2*

While calling from repository

```
val mCoordinate : List<Double> = [22.333, 22.22]
mStateService?.getStatesByCoordinates(mCoordinate.toString().replace(" ", ""))!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterable to encapsulate the integer list, or use a two-dimensional integer array.

- How to define:

  ```
  public interface ServerService {
      @GET("service")
      Call<Result> method1(@Query("array") Iterable<List<Integer>> array);

      @GET("service")
      Call<Result> method2(@Query("array") Integer[][] array);
  }
  ```
- How to use:

  ```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("http://server/")
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .build();
  ServerService service = retrofit.create(ServerService.class);

  // Use the first method.
  List<Integer> data1 = Arrays.asList(0,1,3,5);
  Iterable array1 = Arrays.asList(data1);
  Call<Result> method1Call = service.method1(array1);

  // Use the second method.
  Integer[] data2 = new Integer[]{0,1,3,5};
  Integer[][] array2 = new Integer[][]{data2};
  Call<Result> method2Call = service.method2(array2);

  // Execute enqueue() or execute() of method1Call or method2Call.
  ```

---

Please refer to the code [ParameterHandler.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/ParameterHandler.java) of Retrofit2 for the reason why the way can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value as below

**In Repository**

getApiResponse(arrayOf(0,1,3,5).contentToString())` In Kotlin.

```
@GET("http://server/service")
suspend fun getApiResponse(@Query("array") array: String): Response
```

It will work.