# Retrofit Params: Array of Arrays (Array of key-value pairs)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to make GET request using Retrofit and one of the parameters is an array of key-value par, or actually, an array of arrays, that looks like this:

```
 [ [1, 10], [50, 100] ]
```

I figured out how to perform this request in POSTMAN:

```
Key: durations[0][0] Value: 1
Key: durations[0][1] Value: 10
```

and so on.
However, I have no idea ho to represent this for Retrofit.
Thank you for help.

EDIT:

I tried to represent it as `@Query("durations[]") List<List<Integer>>` duration; Single entry is a List with two values, start and end. No luck.

Comment: please, first see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590454/add-an-array-as-request-parameter-with-retrofit-2

Comment: I know how to pass an array of primitive values and this is applied in my app. I think this is different because this turns into foo[]=val1&foo[]=val2&foo[]=val3, however array of arrays turns into durations[0][0]=200&durations[0][1]=300&durations[1][0]=300&durations[1][1]=400 and I do not know how to represent it for retrofit. First case it List<Integer>, but what this would be?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use this method

```
Object get( @Query("durations[0][0]") int value1,@Query("durations[0][1]") int value2,
@Query("durations[1][0]") int value3,@Query("durations[1][1]") int value4)
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically this is how I solved this. I just manually built the parameter strings I need and put it into a Map along with value. And in your Retrofit interface make filed as @QueryMap:

```
@QueryMap Map<String, Integer> durations,
```

Have a look at my method that makes parameters:

```
public void prepareDurations(Pair<Integer, Integer> durationValues) {
    Map<String, Integer> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
    if(durationValues!=null) {
        paramsMap.put("durations[0][0]", durationValues.first);
        paramsMap.put("durations[0][1]", durationValues.second);
        setDuration(paramsMap);
    }else {
        setDuration(new HashMap<>());
    }
}
```